# Change the Select dropdown outline border color and style

Tags: php, html, css, magento-1.9

In the IE browser the select drop down has a border differs from its style in chrome and other browsers.

How can we change the select dropdown outline style in IE 10?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: Thanks For your reply but it doesn't help me to solve the problem, and i opened the url in IE 11   All Select Dropdown options in it have the same problem!

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the drop down inside menu inside of a `div` element and giving the `div` the `border` property in CSS?

Comment: It is only in IE 10  and uptill now i can't find the answer for it